# stack.sh - OpenStack installation failed

Tags: debian, openstack

I think it's 45th time I'm trying to install OpenStack - I've tried all possible methods I know ( openstack-deploy, manual, stack.sh ) .. but I'm still getting some problem. I would like to have that on single machine, on Debian Jessie.

This is why I came back to stack.sh, and currently I'm getting that error:

```
2015-05-19 11:45:03.607 | + [[ -n '' ]]
2015-05-19 11:45:03.607 | + sleep 3
2015-05-19 11:45:06.621 | ++ echo -ne '\015'
2015-05-19 11:45:06.621 | + NL=$'\r'
2015-05-19 11:45:06.621 | + [[ -n '' ]]
2015-05-19 11:45:06.622 | + screen_rc g-api '/usr/local/bin/glance-api --config-file=/etc/glance/glance-api.conf'
2015-05-19 11:45:06.622 | + SCREEN_NAME=stack
2015-05-19 11:45:06.622 | + SCREENRC=/opt/stack/devstack/stack-screenrc
2015-05-19 11:45:06.622 | + [[ ! -e /opt/stack/devstack/stack-screenrc ]]
2015-05-19 11:45:06.622 | + grep g-api /opt/stack/devstack/stack-screenrc
2015-05-19 11:45:06.624 | ++ echo -ne '\015'
2015-05-19 11:45:06.625 | + NL=$'\r'
2015-05-19 11:45:06.625 | + echo 'screen -t g-api bash'
"'15-05-19 11:45:06.625 | + echo 'stuff "/usr/local/bin/glance-api --config-file=/etc/glance/glance-api.conf
2015-05-19 11:45:06.625 | + [[ -n /opt/stack/logs ]]
2015-05-19 11:45:06.625 | + echo 'logfile /opt/stack/logs/g-api.log.2015-05-19-132546'
2015-05-19 11:45:06.625 | + echo 'log on'
2015-05-19 11:45:06.625 | + screen -S stack -p g-api -X stuff '/usr/local/bin/glance-api --config-file=/etc/glance/glance-api.conf & echo $! >/opt/stack/status/stack/g-api.pid; fg || echo "g-api fa'led to start" | tee "/opt/stack/status/stack/g-api.failure"
2015-05-19 11:45:06.628 | + echo 'Waiting for g-api (10.27.200.17:9292) to start...'
2015-05-19 11:45:06.628 | Waiting for g-api (10.27.200.17:9292) to start...
2015-05-19 11:45:06.628 | + wait_for_service 60 http://10.27.200.17:9292
2015-05-19 11:45:06.629 | + local timeout=60
2015-05-19 11:45:06.629 | + local url=http://10.27.200.17:9292
2015-05-19 11:45:06.629 | + timeout 60 sh -c 'while ! curl -g -k --noproxy '\''*'\'' -s http://10.27.200.17:9292 >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done'
2015-05-19 11:45:09.686 | + is_service_enabled g-search
2015-05-19 11:45:09.690 | + return 1
2015-05-19 11:45:09.690 | + is_service_enabled g-reg
2015-05-19 11:45:09.694 | + return 0
2015-05-19 11:45:09.695 | ++ openstack token issue -c id -f value
2015-05-19 11:45:10.605 | WARNING: keystoneclient.auth.identity.generic.base Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
2015-05-19 11:45:10.609 | ERROR: openstack Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)
2015-05-19 11:45:10.663 | + TOKEN=
2015-05-19 11:45:10.663 | ++ err_trap
2015-05-19 11:45:10.663 | ++ local r=1
2015-05-19 11:45:10.667 | Error on exit
```

and in logs "inside" stack.sh

```
2015-05-19 13:45:00.428747   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/contrib/federation/idp.py", line 21, in <module>
2015-05-19 13:45:00.429038     import saml2
2015-05-19 13:45:00.429078   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/saml2/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
2015-05-19 13:45:00.429446     from elementtree import ElementTree
2015-05-19 13:45:00.429512 ImportError: No module named elementtree
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602124 mod_wsgi (pid=26111): Target WSGI script '/var/www/keystone/admin' cannot be loaded as Python module.
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602177 mod_wsgi (pid=26111): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/keystone/admin'.
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602210 Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602245   File "/var/www/keystone/admin", line 25, in <module>
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602291     application = wsgi_server.initialize_application(name)
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602309   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/server/wsgi.py", line 38, in initialize_application
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602352     common.configure()
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602367   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/server/common.py", line 28, in configure
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602390     config.configure()
2015-05-19 13:45:10.602406   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/common/config.py", line 1106, in configure
2015-05-19 13:45:10.603025     help='Do not monkey-patch threading system modules.'))
2015-05-19 13:45:10.603049   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 1798, in __inner
2015-05-19 13:45:10.603967     result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
2015-05-19 13:45:10.603987   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 1971, in register_cli_opt
2015-05-19 13:45:10.604013     raise ArgsAlreadyParsedError("cannot register CLI option")
2015-05-19 13:45:10.604044 ArgsAlreadyParsedError: arguments already parsed: cannot register CLI option
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608123 mod_wsgi (pid=26110): Target WSGI script '/var/www/keystone/admin' cannot be loaded as Python module.
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608160 mod_wsgi (pid=26110): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/keystone/admin'.
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608191 Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608224   File "/var/www/keystone/admin", line 25, in <module>
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608268     application = wsgi_server.initialize_application(name)
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608286   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/server/wsgi.py", line 38, in initialize_application
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608311     common.configure()
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608327   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/server/common.py", line 28, in configure
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608351     config.configure()
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608366   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/common/config.py", line 1106, in configure
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608390     help='Do not monkey-patch threading system modules.'))
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608406   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 1798, in __inner
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608431     result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608447   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 1971, in register_cli_opt
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608471     raise ArgsAlreadyParsedError("cannot register CLI option")
2015-05-19 13:45:10.608500 ArgsAlreadyParsedError: arguments already parsed: cannot register CLI option
```

I've seen that

```
elementtree import ElementTree
ImportError: No module named elementtree
```

And verified that it should be provided by python-lxml - but I've confirmed it's already installed - I've solved that issue with

```
pip install elementtree --allow-external elementtree --allow-unverified elementtree
```

but now another problem

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8
```

I did not expected such - as python is compiled properly - I don't know why one module is compiled other way...

Comment: Why are you trying to use Debian? If you want an OpenStack that actually works, try [RDO](https://www.rdoproject.org/) on CentOS or Fedora.

Comment: Are you starting with an official image from http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/openstack/ ?

Comment: Ha ! found issue - /usr/local/lib .. I've previously compiled python manually - and forgot to remove it - stack.sh works fine with precompiled python from debian package

Comment: I never faced issue with Debian. Could you check if Python is proper?
This is nothing to do with devstack, something seems wrong with Python.